# combine two arrays by key position

Tags: php, arrays, geojson

I'm trying to create geoJson out from this:

```
(48.178, 16.410),(48.175, 16.408),(48.174, 16.414),(48.176, 16.415)
```

After I created an array I split it with  preg_grep in two:

```
Array ( [1] => 16.410 [3] => 16.408 [5] => 16.414 [7] => 16.415 ) 

Array ( [0] => 48.178 [2] => 48.175 [4] => 48.174 [6] => 48.176 )
```

What I want to do actually, is to exchange latitude an longitude.

How can I combine these arrays by key position?
the result should be

```
Array ( [1] => 16.410 [0] => 48.178 [3] => 16.408 [2] => 48.175 ......... )
```

Comment: Do you really need the original keys preserved in the output array?

Comment: actually not. i reset them, then used Marcin's code and finaly removed 1st dimension of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do ordinary loop with step by 2 and build new array:

```
$out = array();
$count = count($src);
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i+=2) {
    $out[] = $src[$i];
    $out[] = $src[$i+1];
}
```

Note that if you want keys preserved then you shouldn't use numeric keys, but i.e. strings instead. And, in fact, you should consider building multidimensional array instead:

```
    $out[] = array($src[$i], $src[$i+1]);
```

as by logic this data are paired.

Comment: Thank You Marcin. Your Code is OK